# Android run any activity in background?

Tags: android, android-intent

Let's suppose I have two activities A and B. Activity A contains a button, and I want to start Activity B(in background) when that button is pressed.

Comment: you want to press a button from an activity that is in the background??!?

Comment: No i want to start that activity (B) with button press which in in Activity (A)

Comment: if you wanna run activity in background, then what are android [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for? kindly use service for that  which are basicly UI-less Activities

Comment: So basically you want an Activity A containing a button and when you press it, it starts Activity B?

Comment: Yes Eselfar i want same but in backround

Comment: Who will press the button in the background?

Comment: sorry i have question mistake that u guys can,t understand please review my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to potentially do this. Maybe the simplest way would be to use this line on your `onCreate` of your new Activity (that you would start with a new intent)

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

You could also start a broadcast intent which then the other Activity will get a call to `onReceive` even if it is in the background.